# Parsing xml document using iterparse()

Tags: python, xml

I have a large xml file "abcd.xml" of almost 800 MB.I wanted to get the Information of a list of books, if the user input matches with Author or title.

I have done it with a small file,How can i do it with a large file using the iterparse().

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
<dblp>
<article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Saxena96">
<author>Sanjeev Saxena</author>
<title>Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.</title>
<pages>607-619</pages>
<year>1996</year>
<volume>33</volume>
<journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
<number>7</number>
<url>db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96</url>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466</ee>
</article>
```

Coding:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
data = ET.parse('abcd.xml')
root = ET.fromstring(data)

title = raw_input('enter the name: ')
article = root.xpath('.//article[starts-with(title, "%s")]' % title)[0]

for prop in ['author', 'pages', 'year', 'volume', 'journal']:
    print article.findtext(prop)
```

Output Structure:-

```
Sanjeev Saxena
Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.
607-619
1996
33
Acta Inf.
........
........
........
```

Comment: means we have many `<article>` tags and we have to take `title` value from the user. The output will me list of book titles?

Comment: @VivekSable ya,but i need to get along with the other tags too.

Comment: other tags means `'author', 'pages', 'year', 'volume', 'journal'` these? I we create list of dictionary for that? i.e. [{"title":"title value", "author":"author name",...}, {}, {}..]

Comment: What will output structure?

Comment: @VivekSable The output structure is edited,and the  `....` represents next similar book matching the title or author name and goes on.

Comment: Ok, I will back in next 1.30 hr, now going to home. Can you email me input file sample vivekbsable@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse input file by `lxml` module
2. Get Title name from the User by `raw_input()`
3. Target `article` tag who `title` start with User input in step2.
4. Iterate every `article` tags from the step 3
5. Create List of list tuple which save all articles tag and its text information in th result.
6. Print result.

Code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
root = ET.parse('input.xml')

title = raw_input('enter the name: ')
articles = root.xpath('.//article[starts-with(title, "%s")]' % title)
result = []
for article in articles:
    tmp = []
    for i in article.getchildren():
        tmp.append((i.tag, i.text))

    result.append(tmp)

#- Print result:
for i in result:
    print "\n"
    for j in i:
        print "%s:%s"%(j[0], j[1])
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/anna$ python 3.py 
enter the name: Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation


author:Sanjeev Saxena
title:Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.
pages:607-619
year:1996
volume:33
journal:Acta Inf.
number:7
url:db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96
ee:http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466


author:Sanjeev Saxena
title:Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.11
pages:607-619
year:1996
volume:33
journal:Acta Inf.
number:7
url:db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96
ee:http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466

vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/anna$
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how to apply `iterparse()`.